# I need a code compiler but I don't know how to do it. I make apps using Android Studio

Tags: android, compiler-construction

I am a new mobile app developer. I'm building an app for learning programming languages. So I need a code compiler but I don't know how to do it. I make apps using Android Studio. Please help me, how do I make it. Please share any resources like youtube videos, books, tutorials, etc. Note: Without webview.(I want a built-in compiler)

Comment: Do you need an existing compiler/interpreter for an existing languaje or you want to create a new compiler/interpreter?

Comment: I want to create a new compiler.

Comment: Create a compiler is not an easy work. You need to have a good understanding of theory of computation and compiler design. You can read "Crafting interpreters" (the book explains interpreters, but is a good, moder and well explainable guide and most of the techniques are extrapolable to compilers), or get the compiler dragon book (search it in google). Also, You can see videos on youtube about compiler design or take the existent course on geeks for geeks (the only one I found about compilers).

All this effort is not worth for your case. Probably you just want to use an existing one.

Comment: Thanks, please tell me how I use an existing one?

Comment: Just search on google a compiler for the languaje you want. For example, in C  gcc compiler is the most used